# Extracting text using Selenium in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get some information from this site: https://www.websro.com.br/rastreamento-correios.php?P_COD_UNI=LX991645039CN

**I need the status (on this page)**  - Objeto recebido pelos Correios do Brasil

**date** - Data: 17/03/2023 às 07:57

**location** - Local: CURITIBA / PR

[image: code]

I tried many things but couldnt make it work:

```
Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementsByClass("container")(1).FindElementsByCss("row")(4).Text
    
Cells(linha, 13).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementsByClass("container")(1).FindElementsByclassName("bold eventoLocal")(1).Text
```

Almost got there using:

```
Cells(linha, 13).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementsByClass("container")(1).FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/span[1]/").Text
```

but it gets the text between the span, I want the text after the /span

None worked, tried to find on internet and nothing.
Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the code to pick all three parts of the status

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbCorreios()
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772068/extracting-text-using-selenium-in-vba
' https://www.websro.com.br/rastreamento-correios.php?P_COD_UNI=LX991645039CN
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim we As WebElement
    Dim sURL, sTBODY As String
    Dim iLocalPosition, iACLASSPosition
    Dim iDataPosition, ieventoStatusPosition
    Dim iminhasPosition
    sURL = "https://www.websro.com.br/rastreamento-correios.php?P_COD_UNI=LX991645039CN"
    Dim sFilename As String
    Call driver.Start("edge", sURL)
    driver.get (sURL)
    driver.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")

'    span class="bold eventoLocal" Local:  /span CURITIBA / PR<a class="btn-floating track-fab waves-effect waves-light white"
'                                  ^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^
'   !--------!---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!
'   iLocalPosition = the string Local: is unique in the element TBODY and the status we are looking for starts 14 characters after this.
'   iACLASSPosition = the string <a class= can be used to delimit the end of the status, the status string ends before the <
'   iLocalPosition = a string Local: é única no elemento TBODY e o status que procuramos começa 14 caracteres depois disso.
'   iACLASSPosition = a string <a class= pode ser usada para delimitar o final do status, a string de status termina antes do <
'
    sTBODY = we.FindElementByTag("tbody").Attribute("outerHTML")
    iLocalPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "Local:")
    iACLASSPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "<a class=")
    MsgBox Mid(sTBODY, iLocalPosition + 14, iACLASSPosition - (iLocalPosition + 14))
    
'    span class="bold" Data:  /span 17/03/2023 às 07:57 br  span class="bold eventoStatus" Objeto recebido pelos Correios do Brasil /span
    iDataPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "Data:")
    ieventoStatusPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "eventoStatus")
    MsgBox Mid(sTBODY, iDataPosition + 13, ieventoStatusPosition - (iDataPosition + 13) - 22)
    
'    span class="bold eventoStatus" Objeto recebido pelos Correios do Brasil /span  br Local: Unidade Operacional - Curitiba / PR br  span class="minhasImportacoes" Acesse o ambiente  a href=
    ieventoStatusPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "eventoStatus")
    iminhasPosition = InStr(1, sTBODY, "minhasImportacoes")
    MsgBox Mid(sTBODY, ieventoStatusPosition + 14, iminhasPosition - (ieventoStatusPosition + 14) - 70)
    
    driver.Quit
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub 'old skool delay
```

I allocated the `tbody` element to a string and then cut the string up using the MID() function and the INSTR() function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
Using xpatch I got the inner span text, i would like to get the outer span. I found many people with similar problems but all using java or python, and I couldnt find a way to convert this to VBA.

Comment: Using mid, IDK if will work, I can get the whole TD, something like this:

"Local: CURITIBA / PR

Data: 11/03/2023 às 17:10

Faltam informações. Sua ação é necessária
Local: Unidade de Logística Integrada - Curitiba / PR
Acesse o ambiente Minhas Importações"

I dont know how to brake down, since it changes deppenging on the status of the package.

Comment: wow! looks nice, i'll try later and check if everything works, but i'm almost sure that, if dont fully work I can adapt to my needs. Thank you so much