# Selenium extract data after </strong>

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm tying to extract the phone data after a `</strong>` in this web page code:`<strong class="styles__SCSectionTitleTitle-sc-v0nzb6-5 hCjKsp">Teléfonos</strong>669794282`

Using the xpath `OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/div/div[3]/li/div/div//strong").Text`, I only get the word "Teléfonos".

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance,

[image: code_image]

Comment: Have you tried the `ExecuteScript()` method? Isn't working?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm not quite used tu use selenium code, so I don't know how to place it. In fact, if I copy and paste the code, I get the error: "an expression was expected"

Comment: Try with Regex, Check my updated answer.

Comment: You could try using the priciple in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772068/extracting-text-using-selenium-in-vba/75772694#75772694   Pick the enclosing `div` styles__SCSectionTitle-sc-v0n... and then cut the text you need from the text of the resulting web element. It is hard to see what you need without the source code of the URL you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First identify the parent element `div` of child `strong` have a text `Teléfonos`

Then use the `ExecuteScript` to get the node values.

```
OBJ.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;', OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//div[./strong[text()='Teléfonos']]"))

OBJ.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//div[./strong[text()='Teléfonos']]"))

OBJ.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//div[./strong[text()='Teléfonos']]"))

OBJ.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//div[./strong[text()='Teléfonos']]"))
```

---

Alternatively you can use `regex` to `extract` the `number` value from a string.

```
parentDivText=OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//div[.//strong[text()='Teléfonos']]").Text
Dim re As Object
Dim PhoneNumbers

Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "\d{9}"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Set PhoneNumbers = re.Execute(parentDivText)
PhoneNumber=PhoneNumbers(1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but is returnig only a dot, as the phone number has no "pattern", only numbers. Anyway, how can I split the string given by ParentDivText in separate cells in my sheet?

Comment: @G.Asins, print the text here from `ParentDivText` so that can see how it is coming?

Comment: NIF B98173511Número D-U-N-S ® 462059372
FICHA
INFORMA ESTRATÉGICO
INFORMA FINANCIERO
INFORMA COMERCIAL
INFORMA ABREVIADO
INFORMA INVESTIGADO
INFORMES MODULARES
FATCA (Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act)
CRS (Common Reporting and Due Diligence Standards)
DESCUBRE MÁS
Identificación
DENOMINACIÓN
FUTURA INSURANCE AGENCIA DE SUSCRIPCION SL.
DENOMINACIÓN ANTIGUA
RENTA 2009 Y ASOCIADOS SL
TELÉFONOS
960800339
DOMICILIO SOCIAL
CALLE DEL METGE ESTEVE , 10 - 9
46007 VALENCIA
NÚMERO DE SUCURSALES
1

Comment: comes as in a column with the values separated by an "enter"

Comment: can you try the updated regex and see if you are getting correct phone number from that text

Comment: Yes, now it works! but, what if the phone number begins with another figure (i.e. 6)?. Thanks

Comment: How come phone number will 6 digits? Please don’t confuse with yourself

Comment: If this resolved your initially query please accepted as an answer, vote for it and close this discussion. If you have any further scenario I appreciate please post a new question.Thanks.